# mySql – How to search for available IDs

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a mySQL table, which stores data of a user list and has an ID in unsigned tiny-int format (0 to 255 entries possible) as primary key. I enabled auto-increment in order to automatically set the key, which works fine so far.

When users log off I call `ALTER TABLE sj_userlist AUTO_INCREMENT=1` which executes without errors.

However, the next logged in user still receives the ID+1 of the currently highest ID.

Example:

1. 10 Users are online with the IDs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2. Users 1 and 2 to 9 log out - only ID 1 and 10 are still logged on
3. a new user logs in and receives ID 11 but I want him/her to get the 2

In case this behavior is correct, how can I achieve an alternative solution, which always starts at 1 incrementing untl the next available ID is found ?

Thanks in advance,
best

Alex

Comment: Why does it need to always start at 1 and why do you have to reset the auto_increment at any point

Comment: This isn't really what an ID column is for.  Why are you doing this in the first place?  What specifically is this table meant to store?  Why are you deleting records from it so often?  If you expect the table to hold many records, why not use an `int` instead of `tinyint`?

Comment: *In case this behavior is correct* Yes, it is absolutely correct for autoincrement. You must alter your ID assign logic from auto_increment to least available.

Comment: Get rid of the AI. Instead create a table with 256 integers and a datetime. Then use UPDATE to update the integer with the oldest date (or, in the event of a tie, oldest date and lowest id). (Presumably there can never be a situation where 256 users are simultaneously logged on)

Comment: @Akina that will likely result in a concurrency problem where two clients will try to assign the same ID at the same time.

Comment: OK - I understand that auto_increment is not the correct choice and will implement it as suggested above. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ADyson There is no concurrency problem while using reservation until success. Simlpe (reserve available number) - (check it is reserved by me) - (if someone managed to rewrite it then repeat).

Comment: @Strawberry *Then use UPDATE to update the integer with the oldest date* It is possible that LRU is still used (some bot, for example).

Comment: @Akina well even if you can achieve that, it's not very efficient compared to auto_increment. Anyway, as we can see neither auto_increment or your idea is particular suitable for this situation - Strawberry's idea is much more feasible.

Comment: @ADyson I don't see the reason to compare with autoincrement technique which is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution.

1. Create a table for users registration. Define username column as unique.
2. Insert max amount of records into it according the datatype (0-255, for example).
3. When the user logs in and needs to register you use

```
UPDATE table
SET name = 'Current user name'
WHERE name IS NULL
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;

SELECT id
FROM table 
WHERE name = 'Current user name';
```

This guarantee that user will get the least available number, and no interference/concurrence problems will occur.

4. When user log out then you use

```
UPDATE table
SET name = NULL
WHERE name = 'Current user name'
```

`id` is now free for re-use by the next user logged in.

If some problems occures on the client side, and user have not logged out correctly then his name will stay registered. But when he logged in the next time he will receive the same `id` - UPDATE will fail but SELECT will return non-freed `id`.

Nevertheless you must clear such old records periodically.

Comment: Thanks Akina - it's useful indeed !